# Jquery $("body").append(data); not apending completely

Tags: jquery, append

I am using the following function to append some page data to my current page.

```
$.get("/some.jsp", function(data) {
    $("body").append(data);
});
```

This code appends the data completely when I am calling the page in desktop browser.

When I am loading this webpage in mobiles, it doesn't append the full data. It only appends half of the data.

I thought get has some limitation on chars, so I make a variable for that jsp page's contents as a string, then passed the string to append to the body as follows,

```
data = "jsp contents";
$("body").append(data);
```

but there is no use.

I checked the data length as follows,

```
console.log("data");
console.log(data.length);
```

It shows 6760 chars, in both desktop and mobile.

Why data is not completely appends in mobile?

Comment: We can assume that `/some.jsp` returns an HTML fragment, not a full document, right?

Comment: use `.appendTo()` instead of `.append()`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, No its full html code for the page

Answer (score 0):

Check your css first. I think css for mobile device is hiding you details.